# Function in WebAPI give me HTTP 404

Tags: http-status-code-404, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have a c # WebAPI where I currently have to functions..

App_Start

```
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApiWithKey",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{passKey}"
            );

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "WithActionApiKey",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{orderId}/{passKey}"
            );
```

Controller

```
// This one returns Http 404
public IEnumerable<Order> GetAllOrders(string passKey)
{}          

// This one works fine
public Order GetOrder(string orderId, string passKey)
{}
```

When I use the Getorder, it works. But the GetAllOrders does not work (I get an HTTP 404)

Why is that, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Generally, `HTTP 404` are returned `when your routing is wrong` or `when your method name is incorrect` (problem with routes), etc., Put a `breakpoint` and debug the application. Just check if the method is hit.

Comment: The method is not hit when I pass a string as parameter like this...
api/orders/GetAllOrders/myparameterstring. But if I remove the parameter like this api/GetAllOrders, then the controller name "GetAllOrders" I can see that the controller name "GetAllOrders" is passed as parameter to that method...?!

Comment: I now see that I didnt have a correct routing (left the action name...)

Comment: Thats it! thats how you find out. Good luck